# Infine Sequence ${1, 3, 2, 3, 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, recursion

I have an infine sequence where at the end of which the ones are written. Then till infinity we shall do the next procedure: for each segment with ends a and b (inside which the numbers are absent) we shall write in the middle the number a + b

Sequence buiding: {${1, 1}$} $-$ {${1, 2, 1}$} $-$ {${1, 3, 2, 3, 1}$} $-$ ${1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1}$

How many times the positive integer n will be written on a segment?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Show how you construct this sequence (give examples of several steps).

Comment: Is that what you are asking: the number $1$ will be written $2$ times and the number $2$ once in every segment and the number $3$ will be written only twice in larger segments

Comment: @Elaqqad Yes, for example number 4 will be written 2 times in infinite sequence

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reasonable pattern to this. For example, iterating fifty times gives a sequence where $5$, $10$, and $12$ (for example) each appear four times, while $17$ appears $16$ times and $19$ appears $18$ times. Given the size of the sequence, these values are probably stable to infinity.

Comment: How many times will $n$ appear on what segment?

Comment: Here's a hint: these are the denominators in the left branch of the Stern-Brocot tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree at successive depths

Answer (score 0):

One observation: the number of occurrences of $n$ in the limit is determined after $n$ iterations (where the first iteration is the original sequence $\{1,1\}$. You can see this inductively. It's clearly true for $n=1$; now suppose that at some point at or after the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ iteration we get another $n$ in the sequence. Then there must have been two adjacent values adding to $n$; since those are both less than $n$, they were added by the $(n-1)^{\mathrm{st}}$ iteration. So we are at the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ iteration.